# Prove that an integer $n > 1$ is prime if and only if the following holds: $(n − 1)! ≡ −1 \pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

So I am trying to prove this as follows:

we know a number $p$ is prime if and only if $Z_p$ is a field. More specifically, if $\forall x \in Z_p,\exists ! x^{-1}\in Z_p$ such that $xx^{-1}\equiv 1\pmod p)$. So considering $(p-1)!$, every term in the factorial from $2$ to $p-2$ has an inverse, so we can replace them both with $1$. So the congruence becomes

$1\times  $(...$\frac{p-1}{2}$ times 1...)$\times (p-1)\equiv (p-1)\equiv -1 \pmod p$.

Is there any problem with this proof?

Comment: That is the Wilson's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem

Comment: That works in one direction, but you also need to argue that $(n-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod n\implies n$ is prime.  (Hint:  that's a lot easier).

Comment: @lulu But didn't I do this in one step in the $p$ is prime if and only if $Z_p$ is a field? $p$ is prime iff $Z_p$ is a field. $Z_p$ is a field iff $(p-1)!\equiv -1$ mod $p$. Therefore $p$ is prime iff $(p-1)!\equiv -1$ mod $p$

Comment: I don't see how you establish the last iff.  In any case, it's trivial.  If $n$ is not prime then there is a prime $q<n$ which divides $n$.  That prime obviously divides $(n-1)!$ so the latter can't be $-1\pmod n$.

Comment: I suppose you could argue that, given $(n-1)!\equiv -1$, then every non-zero class has an inverse,  Specifically, we'd have $-\frac {(n-1)!}a $ as an inverse to $a$, for $1≤a≤n-1$.  That ought to be enough to prove that $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is a field.  But I do think some additional step is required.

Comment: Right, so you mean that my last iff is just a $\rightarrow$ so we need to establish $\leftarrow$ (using your last comment) and hence the second iff? and hence the overall proof?

Comment: That's what I mean, yes.

Comment: I think there's a gap in your proof in that you haven't directly addressed what happens if $x^{-1} \equiv x (\bmod{p}).$  If this happens, then you can't pair $x$ with its inverse and replace them by $1$.